# catch FCM notification and display on scheduled time in React native APP

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

We've setup FCM console to send push notifications to our react native APP.It's working perfectly.
Now we want scheduled push notifications for selected users on the APP.

so we need to catch FCM notifications and display those notifications on scheduled time stamp.(may be using some parameters on the payload. Ex:- **"isScheduled": "true", "scheduledTime": "Thu Apr 20 2023 09:00:00 GMT+1000"** )

We are using react native.

if anybody can suggest us the best way to do it with some example, it'll be great help...

looking for the best way to do it.